# Convert txt to HTML with batch file

Tags: html, parsing, batch-file, contains

I have plain txt file like:

```
===
Date:30.05.2013
**Header**
text

===
Date:29.05.2013
**Header**
text

===
etc.
```

I want to convert it into html file like:

```
<hr>
<b>Date:30.05.2013</b>
<h1>Header</h1>
text
<br>
<hr>
<b>Date:29.05.2013</b>
<h1>Header</h1>
text
<br>
<hr>
etc.
```

I know about "for" command, i use it

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type news.txt') do (
if [%%f]==[===] (echo ^<hr/^> >>news.htm) ELSE (echo %%f^<br/^> >>news.htm)
)
```

But i dont know, **how perform other action for strings that contains keyword** (e.g. Date or *) and dont know, how insert blank br tag for blank strings in text file.

Please, help me, i spent many hours =(

Comment: i cant use any server-side scripts, only plain console apps

Comment: You can run a Markdown parser from the command line.

Comment: Where i can get Markdown parser for windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "br=^<br^>"
SET "hr=^<hr^>"
SET "h1=^<h1^>"
SET "sh1=^</h1^>"
SET "bold=^<b^>"
SET "sbold=^</b^>"

(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('type news.txt^|findstr /n "$"') DO (
SET line=%%i&CALL :process
)
)>news.html

GOTO :eof

:process
:: remove line number from line
SET "line=%line:*:=%"
IF NOT DEFINED line ECHO(%br%&GOTO :EOF
SET "line2=%line:"=_%"
SET "line3=%line:"=%"
IF NOT "%line2%"=="%line3%" GOTO rawout
IF "%line%"=="==="  ECHO(%hr%&GOTO :EOF
IF "%line:~0,5%"=="Date:"  ECHO(%bold%%line%%sbold%&GOTO :EOF
IF "%line:~0,2%%line:~-2%"=="****" ECHO(%h1%%line:~2,-2%%sh1%&GOTO :EOF
:rawout
ECHO(!line!%br%
GOTO :eof
```

This should work for you. It numbers each line, then assigned the numbered line to `line`. This is a common technique since `for /f` will skip empty lines.

`:process` merely looks for keystrings and outputs an appropriate replacement.

I've used a shortcut on detecting 'begins and ends "**"`. There are more reliable ways of doing it - but it should only fail if the line is`***`or`**` - relatively easy to fix if it's a problem...

(edit 20130531-0134Z new `:process` procedure to changed specification)

{re-edit 20130531-0750Z add enabledelayedexpansion to setlocal and echo !line! after :rawout to suit unbalanced-quotes}

Comment: It great! One moment - last line must be ECHO(%line%%br%

Comment: One bug, that if string contain quote " script stop and no more parse. How fix it?

Comment: magnificently! one much more small bug - if i use only one quote in string, it visible, but with excess ^ symbol.

Comment: And one more wish - parse links to net disk folders and files. E.g. "Q:\Project\Blabla\File.txt" must be converted in a link on this file. I think, possible find construction like "Q:\" or "\\server\"

Comment: Unbalanced-quotes fixed. Not sure what you mean by your link-conversion. Qhat pattern needs to be found, and replaced by what (explicitly)

Comment: Pattern "Q:\anytexthere". i.e. search text in quotes by first three (or more)symbols after open quote

Comment: I use this construction for autocreate marked lists:
`IF "%line:~0,1%"=="-" ECHO(%li%%line:~1,100%%sli%&GOTO :EOF` it work, but if string contain quote - it not work. Why is that?

Comment: `"%line:~0,1%"=="-"` is evaluated as `"contains"quote"=="-"` The parser believes that the first string is `"contains"` and doesn't understand `quote` since it's expecting `==`. Note how I've set `line2` and `line3`. This replaces the `"` in `line` with `_` or `:`. The point is that `line2`==`line3` ONLY if the two lines DO NOT contain `"`. If you were to try `IF "%line2:~0,1%"=="-" ECHO(%li%!line:~1!%sli%&GOTO :eof` - that will work (note the use of !line:~1! - this postpones the evaluation until AFTER the parser has finished. Also, a missing "length" gives "the rest of the string".